# Reached max children process limit: 2, extra: 0, current: 2, busy: 2, please increase LSAPI_CHILDREN

Tags: jelastic, litespeed

We are using 2 lb +  2 api's + 3 mysql   for running our burger website.   During peak order  time website get slow and some time not available.  We have checked the logs in detail and we could see the below in  API  litespeed error logs

> [STDERR] [24627] Reached max children process limit: 2, extra: 0,
> current: 2, busy: 2, please increase LSAPI_CHILDREN

[image]
[image]

We have tried raising the LSAPI_CHILDREN and other limits via litespeed admin url meanwhile the setting is not getting affected on back end.    We get the same error again,  when we have tried api cluster restart the settings are again reverted to the same.

I am attaching the screen shot of the changes we have done,  the above error log is continuously logged after the change and litespeed restart.    Due to continuous down issues we are moving to nginx for now.    We need a proper solution for this so that we can use litespeed again.

Comment: check PHP external app in your vhost level?

Comment: There is nothing defined there.  See the screen shot.  
https://ibb.co/0Zzd9Bb

Answer (score 2):

You may use (add & set) the variable `LSWS_MAX_CHILDREN` in the LSWS layer (in your case) or in LLSMP layer (in case when LLSMP layer is used) to set the maximum children process limit for the server via the Dashboard.
The variables list access
[image: The layer variables]

Add and set the variable
[image: Add&set the LSWS_MAX_CHILDREN variable]

Restart is required to apply changes.

To ensure the best operability, Jelastic sets this value equal to the number of available CPU cores (by default) and due to it this variable is not visible in the variable list. For more details, please follow the link [LiteSpeed Web Server](https://docs.jelastic.com/litespeed-web-server/).

To read more about environment variables configuration, the below-listed links could be also in use:
[Variables](https://docs.jelastic.com/container-variables/) 
[Container Configuration](https://docs.jelastic.com/container-configuration/#container-layer-settings-wizard)